# Odd behavior in ASP.NET query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

I am trying to build a query in my code behind and connect it to a datasource to reload the data.  Unfortunately the query only works when Author is included in the where clause.  Otherwise I get no results returned.

For example:

1. Search for author (king) alone, returns accurate results.

   ```
   SELECT 
       [Title], [Author], [Category], [Image], [Binding], [Price], 
       [ProductID], [Average Rating] AS Average_Rating 
   FROM [tblProducts] 
   WHERE (Author LIKE ‘%king%')
   ```
2. Search for author (king) and title (dif), returns accurate results.

   ```
   SELECT 
       [Title], [Author], [Category], [Image], [Binding], [Price],        
       [ProductID], [Average Rating] AS Average_Rating 
   FROM [tblProducts] 
   WHERE (Author LIKE '%king%') AND (Title LIKE ‘%dif%’)
   ```
3. Search for title (dif) alone, no results returned.

   ```
   SELECT 
       [Title], [Author], [Category], [Image], [Binding], [Price], 
       [ProductID], [Average Rating] AS Average_Rating 
   FROM [tblProducts] 
   WHERE (Title LIKE ‘%dif%')
   ```
4. If all user entered values are empty, no results returned.

   ```
   SELECT 
       [Title], [Author], [Category], [Image], [Binding], [Price], 
       [ProductID], [Average Rating] AS Average_Rating 
   FROM [tblProducts]
   ```

I am sure it is something simple that I am missing, but I can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my relevant code:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.AccessDataSource tmpAccessConnection = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.AccessDataSource();

    //Set file location
    //Connection strings are not used with unprotected Access databases
    tmpAccessConnection.DataFile = "~/App_Data/propdbA2003.mdb";
    tmpAccessConnection.ID = "adsPropertyListing";
    tmpAccessConnection.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataSet;

    //build query
    tmpAccessConnection.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Title], [Author], [Category], " +
    "[Image], [Binding], [Price], [ProductID], [Average Rating] AS Average_Rating " +
    " FROM [tblProducts]";

    String stmntWhere = "";

    if (!textAuthor.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        stmntWhere += "(Author LIKE '%" + textAuthor.Text + "%')";
    }

    if (!textBookTitle.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        if(!stmntWhere.Equals(""))
            stmntWhere += " AND "; //add AND if the stmnt has other parameters
        stmntWhere += "(Title LIKE '%" + textBookTitle.Text + "%')";
    }

    if (!textISBN.Text.Equals(""))
    {
        if (!stmntWhere.Equals(""))
            stmntWhere += " AND "; //add AND if the stmnt has other parameters
        stmntWhere += "((ISBN LIKE '%" + textISBN.Text + "%')" + 
                    " OR (ISBN13 LIKE '%" + textISBN.Text + "%'))";
    }

    if (checkInclude.Checked)
    {
        if (!stmntWhere.Equals(""))
           stmntWhere += " AND "; //add AND if the stmnt has other parameters
        stmntWhere += "(Category = " + dropDwnCategory.SelectedValue + ")";
    }

    if (!stmntWhere.Equals(""))
        tmpAccessConnection.SelectCommand += " WHERE " + stmntWhere;

    adsSearch.SelectCommand = tmpAccessConnection.SelectCommand;
    anAccessDataSource.SelectCommand = tmpAccessConnection.SelectCommand;
    gridViewBrowseAll.DataSourceID = "adsSearch";

    //reset page to 1st page if new search is initiated from revised query
    gridViewBrowseAll.PageIndex = 0;

    //Set AutoGenerateColumns property to true in code or web form
    try
    {
        gridViewBrowseAll.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Binding exception in btnPropNoSearch_Click<BR>");
        Response.Write("Access Exception Handler: {0} " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Its more easy for you to debug step by step your code, than anyone else do that on their mine.

Comment: The code is working as intended with respect to building the query.  So I guess my question it this: Are there issues with the query? or do I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: You could step-by-step debug your code and see the query formed just before execution. Then you could execute it in SQL Server Management Studio to find out what is going wrong... Anyway, forming an SQL query string and then executing it is never a good idea. I would kindly suggest to consider using another approach for your next project (Entity Framework, other ORM etc).

Comment: You should really work on how to query a database! 1. make use of `parameters` (see [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1(v=vs.100).aspx) , 2. use [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227680(v=vs.100).ASPX) for your dataSource 3. use `Debug.WriteLine(..)` insteaed of Response.Write if you need to print out something

Comment: That is just a copy paste issue.

Comment: I suspect it's having a problem with the word 'Title'.  try wrapping that in brackets [] and let us know if it helps.  Also, you're pulling [ProductID] but searching by [ISBN] and [ISBN13] - is this intentional?

Comment: Oddly, removing the assignment of the SelectCommand from the anAccessDataSource object solved the problem.  The query now correctly generates correct answers in all instances.